# Перевести byte [] в строку и обратно Java

Tags: java, android, строки, byte, bytearray

```
byte [] enc = {78, -21, -18, 84, 86, 80, 61, 61, -120, -52, 120, -88, 63, -128, -83, -89, 126, -4, -81, -111, 39, 7};
String enc_str = new String(enc, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte [] enc_new = enc_str.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(enc == enc_new);
```

Выводит **false**, что делать? Получаются абсолютно **разные** массивы.

Comment: Вы сравниваете ссылки, равенство можно проверить методом Arrays.equals(array1, array2); (ну или что-то подобное)

Comment: @Ilnar спасибо! помогло, Arrays.toString(enc_new) переводит массив в строку!

Answer (score 1):

Массивы сравнить можно так: `Arrays.equals(enc, enc_new);`
Перевести массив в строку: `Arrays.toString(enc_new);`

Спасибо @Ilnar !!!